# Should I not do Triage when I am out of votes?

Tags: discussion, triage, upvotes

When I triage a question as "Looks OK" I get dunned about up-voting it even if might be out of votes for the day.

So, that raises the question in my mind:

*If I am out of votes for the day, should I stop triaging?*

Comment: Does choosing _"Looks OK"_ automatically come with an upvote? I don't think so (hopefully).

Comment: No but it pretty emphatically urges you to up-vote it.

Comment: You probably shouldn't. That's one thing I'm experiencing as _monkey upvoters_ here annoyingly.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  If that's the "official position", may I suggest it not let you?

Comment: I don't understand the term *monkey upvoters* ....

Comment: _"Looks OK"_ is just what it is, not necessarily deserves an upvote. The term _monkey upvoters_ is for people just judgeing from looking of a question, without really judging the contents.

Comment: I didn't vote on the question, but I assume the downvotes *could* mean "it's up to you whether you want to stop triaging just because you've run out of votes." Downvoting is applied much more liberally here on Meta; you lose no rep for them

Comment: Wait what? I thought you couldn't review Triage if you're out of votes. Or is that another queue. Or is that flags? I'm so confused...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (up|down)voting is just not the main purpose of Triage. Hence, it doesn't matter whether you're out of (up|down)votes or not.

Comment: Thank you.  If I find a particularly good question in Triage while out of votes, I guess I'll just skip it to give somebody else the chance to make it more noticeable.